# Hyperdimension Neptunia orderly list of dungeons appearance

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia

So, what is the orderly list of appearance of the game's dungeons in the anime? I'm pretty sure that based on the enemy (Dogoo) and the landscape, the first dungeon showed in the anime is Virtua Forest, but what about the rest, like the R-18 island? And since the game consist of several series, which version of the game the featured dungeon is based on?

Note: I played Rebirth 2 and only tried the prologue of Rebirth 1. But so far I can tell, the world map is different and the landscape of the first dungeon (both are Virtua Forest) is different too. Therefore, in the answer please specify which version of the game.